# How to get direct return value instead of <MagicMock name='mock.xx' id='yy'>

Tags: unit-testing

This is my testing code :

```
import mock
import unittest


def check_method_return(input):
    return_value = input.ops.list()

    if not return_value:
        return False

    return return_value


def check_method_len(input):

    return_value = input.ops.list()

    if len(return_value) < 1:
        return False

    return return_value

class TestMockReturnValue(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_mock_return(self):
        fake_input = mock.MagicMock()
        fake_input().ops.list.return_value = []

        result = check_method_return(fake_input)
        self.assertFalse(result)


    def test_mock_len(self):
        fake_input = mock.MagicMock()
        fake_input().ops.list.return_value = []

        result = check_method_len(fake_input)
        self.assertFalse(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_empty = []
    if not test_empty:
        print("empty list equals to False")

    unittest.main()
```

The run result output is :

```
empty list equals to False
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_mock_return (__main__.TestMockReturnValue)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_mock.py", line 31, in test_mock_return
    self.assertFalse(result)
AssertionError: <MagicMock name='mock.ops.list()' id='140459969939728'> is not false

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.005s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Because when the list is empty, its return value for if is False. So, method "check_method_return" should work exactly the same as "check_method_len" in the real world.

So, my question is : 
Is there a way to make the unit test pass for "check_method_return" ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the case, Here is the solution, I cannot explain the exact difference, but it makes sense:

```
    # this mock away input.ops.list()
    fake_input.ops.list.return_value = []


    # this did not mock away input.ops.list()
    fake_input().ops.list.return_value = []
```

To show the difference between 2 ways to set mock_input return value
This could help  to understand better

```
[gliang@www ~]$ ipython
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import unittest

In [2]: import mock

In [3]: fake_input mock.Mag
mock.MagicMixin  mock.MagicMock   mock.MagicProxy

In [4]: fake_input = mock.MagicMock()

In [5]: fake_input().ops.list.return_value= []

In [6]: print fake_input().ops.list.return_value
[]

In [7]: print fake_input.ops.list.return_value
<MagicMock name='mock.ops.list()' id='15160848'>

In [8]: fake_input2 = mock.MagicMock()

In [9]: fake_input2.ops.list.return_value = []

In [10]: print fake_input2.ops.list.return_value
[]

In [11]: quit()
```

Comment: No, what I want to test is check_method_return with the return == False, and it should be Fasle, because  input.ops.list() is return [], and  "if not []" should return True.  I do not understand the second part, can you explain a little more ?

Comment: @ChenLi, the second part is the same as `unittest.main()`, I revised the answer, the only difference is the `input().ops.list` vs `input.ops.list`